# Keep state of user in rails app with extra details

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic, remember-me

I am new to rails , previously I have worked extensively with Yii (PHP, MVC framework) . Yii , allowed web user methods to set state variable , such as

```
Yii::app()->user->userid 
Yii::app()->user->name
```

My rails application needs similar kind of data stored about the user , to be accessed at will . Data such as user's name , role and profile picture name . I am using authlogic and used the following function to store the user's state in session variables :

```
 def login

  @user_session = UserSession.new(:email => params['email'] , :password => params['password'],:remember_me => params['remember_me'] )
  @user = User.where(:email => params['email']).first

      if @user_session.save && @user.access_status = 'active'


             session[:user_name] = @user.name
             session[:user_pic]  = @user.profile_pic_file_name
             session[:user_level] = @user.user_level
             redirect_to :action => 'index'
      else
          ...
      end 
 end
```

This is working fine , however I decided to add a 'remember me' feature . After I close the browser and reopen it my session variable assignments(name,role and picture name) no longer exist and I get all nil values . The user id is still present and user is still logged in .

What would be the best way to implement this ? Can I set the values in authlogic itself(because authlogic does retain the userid even after the browser is closed) or should I resort to cookie stored on the browser ? My application does not have very high security concerns or sensitive data .

I am looking for an elegant solution because the data I intend to store would be used often in multiple places .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to add persistent login then you will need to do so via cookies. You can generate a session key for the user and store the session data in the database. You write this session key to their cookie which allows you to know which session to pull from the DB when the user returns. If you include any user data in this key it's highly recommended that you hash it via a secret key to prevent people from just "making" their own session keys and coming to your site.

Also be aware that persistent sessions like this open up your userbase to session hijaking issues and introduces some additional security concerns. One common thing I do in this scenario is require the user password to make any change to the user's preferences and only depend on the session key for access control.

### Example

---

Have a session model that holds whatever session data you think you will need, this session should belong to a user. Create a `sessions_helpers` file with some functions like:

```
def remember(user)
  # ideally give an expiration
  cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
end

def sign_out
  cookies.delete :remember_token
end

def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end
```

And then inside of your `ApplicationController` just `include SessionHelper` and you have access to these in all of your controllers/views. Allowing you to do `current_user.user_id` to fetch the logged in user id in a controller action.

From the above code you'd also need to define a `remember_token` method on the `User` model. In this example there is no `Session` model or database table it just uses the `User` (which may suit your needs or may not) but adding in a `Session` model would just modify it slightly.